# Entity Framework LINQ - dynamically select properties

Tags: linq, entity-framework, select, dynamic

Is it possible to create a dynamic selector like the below one in a simple way, and how?

```
        Func<Company, string> companyName = x.CompanyName;
        Func<Company, int> companyId = x.CompanyId;

        var result = datacontext.Select(x => new
        {
            CompanyName = companyName,
        CompanyId = companyId
        });
```

The above code throws exception: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Func`2... ...Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

The problem is that I need to dynamically select up to 8 fields out of possible 50 from approximately 10 different tables, and these fields can be of types string, int, datetime nullable and not nullable. It is quiet difficult to dynamically construct a selector with Expressions. What is the best way to tackle this?

Comment: In your top line, what is the value of `x` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = datacontext.Select(x => new
        {
            CompanyName = mcname(x),
            CompanyId = companyId(x)
        });
```

But where is the reason?

Comment: Thanks Hamlet, but this gives an exception "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities", i work with EF.

Comment: About the reason: I create a massive search filter with dynamically selected fields, which later will be displayed in a grid. The filter part is complete but I struggle with the select statement. The final aim is to create a list of anonymous type objects with fixed amount of properties and bind it to the results grid.

Comment: OK, you can use expression tree to build queries. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Comment: I tried that route first, but it soon because too verbose, in my case at least. The final query might have multiple joins, properties of different types, etc. Writing this all for 50 options make code too complex

Answer (score 0):

Your Funcs should look like this:

```
Func<Company, string> companyName = (company => company.CompanyName);
Func<Company, int> companyId = (company => company.CompanyId);
```

To use your func:

```
var result = datacontext.Select(x => new
        {
            CompanyName = companyName(x),
            CompanyId = companyId(x)
        });
```

I don't know of a way to dynamically create a query for specific fields.  You can dynamically chain filters with a single execution though...  Unless you're storing a significant amount of information on each row or are loading hundreds of thousands of rows I wouldn't worry about it.

P.S. You'll want to be careful using custom functions in your primary database filters.  LINQ can't translate all commands to a native SQL query so it may end up pulling an entire table and filtering in within your code.  Just pay attention.

Comment: this throws exception: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but could what you want be done simply like this?

```
    var result = datacontext.Select(x => new
    {
        CompanyName = x.companyName,
        CompanyId = x.companyId
    });
```

Comment: I need to dynamically select 8 out of possible 50 fields in the anonymous object. The fields companyName and companyId are only two of them.